Why is no warning thrown for indexing a Series of values with a bool Series that's too long?
I have the following code:
import pandas as pd

series_source = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int)
normal_index = pd.Series([True, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
big_index = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False, True], dtype=bool)

# Both indexes give back: pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int)
# no warnings are raised!
assert (series_source[normal_index] == series_source[big_index]).all() 

df_source = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]
    ]
)

# no warning - works as expected: grabs rows 0, 2, and 3
df_normal_result = df_source[normal_index]

# UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
# (but still runs)
df_big_result = df_source[big_index]

# passes - they are equivalent
assert df_normal_result.equals(df_big_result)
print("Complete")

Why is it that indexing the series_source with the big_index doesn't raise a warning, even though the big index has more values than the source? What is pandas doing under the hood in order to do the Series indexing?
(Contrast this to indexing the df_source, where an explicit warning is raised that big_index needs to be re-indexed in order for the operation to work.)
In the indexing docs, it claims that:

Using a boolean vector to index a Series works exactly as in a NumPy
ndarray

However, if I do
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])
c = np.array([True, False, True, True, False, True, True])

# returns an ndarray of [1,3, 4] as expected
print(a[b])

# raises IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along axis 0;
# size of axis is 5 but size of corresponding boolean axis is 7
print(a[c])

So it does not seem that this functionality matches Numpy as the docs claim. What's going on?
(My versions are pandas==2.2.2 and numpy==2.0.0.)

Because the indexing Series is first aligned to the index of the indexed DataFrame/Series.
In short, pandas is doing:
tmp = big_index.reindex(df.index)
df_big_result = df_source[tmp]

Example for a Series:
pd.Series([0,1,2])[pd.Series([True, True, False], index=[1,2,0])]

#  1    1
#  2    2
#  dtype: int64

You can actually observe this yourself if you change the indices of the indexing Series:
big_index2 = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, True, True],
                       index=[4,5,0,1,2,3], dtype=bool)
df_source[big_index2]

Output:
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16

We have 4 rows in the output, despite the first two values being False. After reindexing, the boolean values are [True, True, True, True].
You should get a warning in this case:
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

Note that if alignment cannot be done, then an error will be raised, like in numpy:
pd.Series([0,1,2])[pd.Series([True, True, False], index=[1,2,3])]
# IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

pd.Series([0,1,2])[[True, False, False, True]]
# IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 4 instead of 3

why does it happen with DataFrame[Series] but not Series[Series]?
Because there is a check for DataFrame[Series]
# internal for DataFrame.__getitem__
     def __getitem__(self, key):
        # ...
        if isinstance(key, Series) and not key.index.equals(self.index):
            warnings.warn(
                "Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.",
                UserWarning,
                stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
            )

# internal for Series.__getitem__
         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
             key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)
             return self._get_rows_with_mask(key)



Yes, that functionality makes a lot of sense for the DataFrame source, and I understand it. What I'm confused about though is what's going on with the Series source. What happens when you do series_source[big_index]? Why doesn't the behavior match what happens in numpy despite the docs saying that it should?

@ProQ because numpy doesn't have an index to align. Your observation would be the same if you perform an addition for example try: pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]}).add(pd.Series([10,20,30], index=[0,2,4]), axis=0)

My question is "Why doesn't series_source[big_index] raise a warning?" Your answer is "Because the indexing Series is first aligned to the index of the indexed DataFrame." But this answer doesn't make sense because there is no DataFrame in series_source[big_index].

You mean why pandas raises a warning in one case and not the other? Because the internals are in different functions an this is not implemented for Series. Why hasn't it been done is not really on topic.

The pandas docs claim that indexing a series with a boolean series should work just like Numpy. Numpy raises an Exception. Pandas raises no exception or warning and just gives back a value. That's confusion #2 for me. Confusion #1 is what value Pandas is returning (when Numpy would raise an exception). You clearly state (and I agree) that df[big_index] needs reindexing. Are you also claiming that series[big_index] does reindexing? If so, please update your answer.

I added an example that demonstrates that Series also are reindexed. I agree that the term in the documentation is confusing, I would just interpret it as "if you pass an [aligned] Series of booleans, this will select the rows which have True, like in numpy"

Clarifying my learnings from @mozway's answer:
When indexing a pd.Series or pd.DataFrame with a pd.Series[bool], pandas will match the labels of the values in the source series (or the labels of the rows in the source dataframe) to the labels found in the indexing Series. This process is done internally via the reindex method: bool_series.reindex(source.index).
Note that if a label is in the source that is not in the boolean indexer, reindexing is not possible and so the program will raise an error.
If the source is a dataframe and the indexing boolean series's labels do not exactly match the labels of the source dataframe (source_df.index != bool_series.index), then the program will raise a warning indicating that reindexing will be done. However, if the source is a series, and the labels don't exactly match (source_series.index != bool_series.index) then no warning will be raised (it will just silently reindex the boolean series). This is merely an implementation detail.
